# how to customizing fields in django's comment app?

Tags: django

How can I customize the django builtin comment app so that the fields url, email will be ignored and automatically populate the name with the user's username since I'm only allowing comments from authenticated users?

Answer (score 1):

Start here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/comments/custom/#ref-contrib-comments-custom

Comment: Thanks. I actually found it a while ago but I thought I'll just ask here just incase someone knew another way.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the save method to pull user data and set it to comment's field